# Looking for a tool like (IDW) for raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, inverse-distance-weighted

I am looking for a tool that gives the same outputs like the IDW, but for rasters instead of points. I have a Corine land cover raster layer in ArcMap 10.2 with different friction values, displaying habitat suitability for a particular animal species. Among others the layer includes open land and forests. I would like to display different friction values for open land, based on their distance to forest. What means that open land close to forest is better than open land further away from forest. 
I could do that by creating several buffers around the forest raster cells and add these to the original layer, but I am wondering whether there is a tool, that could simplify this.

Comment: IDW is an interpolation tool that estimates values from known points. I'm not sure what you mean by 'same outputs'. I *think* what you want to do is use your forest as in put to [Euclidean distance](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000001p000000) to generate a distance from forest raster. That could then be manipulated in combination with the 'friction values' or possibly Reclassify to generate the suitability raster, with open lands used as a mask.